# Do compilers remove unnecessary parentheses

Tags: java, compiler-construction

For example if I compile this in Java in Eclipse

```
intvar = (int)(((var1 * var3))*(7));
```

will the compiler clean it up to

```
intvar = (int) var1 * var3 * 7;
```

and then would the compiler would do its thing of making it to machine code and stuff.

Or do I have to do something special to the compiler to make it optimize the code?

Also, would this apply to all other languages that are compiled?

Comment: The second line is different from the first line. If `var3` is `double` for example, then the result of second line is `double`. In first line, the result with the same condition, will be `int`

Comment: lets said I never use doubles and just floats but mostly ints

Comment: then there is no point of having second line with (int)

Comment: oops i was just thinking of examples with paratheses not about that stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses don't actually generate code. They are not operations. A parenthesis simply controls the order in which code is output, or rather, the order in which the operations would be performed. So no, you don't need to worry about "unnecessary" parentheses, except for cases where the order influences the result (e.g. where an operation is suddenly performed in floating point instead of integer because of the way you bracket it).

Comment: Well in those cases the parentheses aren't 'unnecessary'.

Answer (score 5):

Compiler translates java code to byte code. Byte code does not have parentheses at all. It works with stacks.

Comment: This is wrong answer. First, compiler transform code into tree, then it optimizes the code (like removing unnecessary casting due to types it produces) and THEN it is transformed into the byte code.

Comment: @libik Can we say this answer is an abstraction over the entire complex process compiler follows behind the scene? And then can we say, this abstraction is not wrong?

Comment: @RohitJain - sure, did you ever try to do the following : create your own language, then create your own compilator to transform it into your own bytecode transformation and then create virtual machine which is able to run it? I did. And I can tell you - even if it is transformed into the byte code, it can contain redundancies if  not optimized.

Comment: libik what was the name of the language you created?

Comment: @ibik There is nothing wrong with this answer. You've provided a bit more detail about it, some of which may or may not apply to a specific Java compiler. However there is nothing incorrect about the answer as stated.

Comment: @androidmaster - it does not have a name, it was a school project (very interesting one). However, it is much more easier than I ever imagined (two people, 4 credits, one semester and it had garbage collector, abstract class and interfaces (we inspired by Java a lot) )

Comment: @libik to me thats mind blowing, am only 15 so am limited to knownledge of programming that I get from tutorials on the internet. I want to take classes when am older to learn C++

Comment: @EJP - there is a LOT wrong with an answer. Question in fact was : "does Java compiler optimize code". And then he added example. That example was not about "real" parenthesis, it was about if it is transformed to something as simple as possible instead of additional casting. AlexR answered in very confusing way that there are not parentheses and it looks like, because of that, the code is "optimized", because it does not have "parenthesis". Im sorry, it is wrong and it always will be.

Comment: @androidmaster - maybe better to start with Java or C#, it is more common these days and it is much more user-friendly. Especially Java, which is very "strict" in many ways. And I like that, because it helps you to not be confused and to do less mistakes.

Comment: @libik I already know lots of Java, am not a beginner. I already know about most of the swing, android dev and other stuff with java. Am been using it the past 2 years :D I also like how Java is strict, that  s why I dont like python or javascript very much...

Comment: @ibik I don't see anything wrong with the answer, or anything confusing about it either. He is quite correct to state that there are no parentheses in byte codes. Your detail about parse trees and optimization isn't actually relevant. A one-pass compiler would behave like this with no parse tree or optimisation phase at all. Removal of redundant parentheses isn't an 'optimisation'. Rather, it happens naturally during parsing. And you've mis-stated the question. It is about removal of redundant parentheses, not whether the Java compiler optimises code.

Comment: @androidmaster - if you want, I can send you everything I told you about (it is written in Java), - libor.vilimek at gmail

Comment: @ibik In fairness to this poster you should therefore remove all your comments saying this answer is wrong. Future readers won't necessarily read all the way to the bottom of this exchange to see your retraction.

Answer (score 5):

Check the bytecode with `javap -c`:

```
intvar = (int)(((var1 * var3))*(7));
```

becomes:

```
   4: iload_1       
   5: iload_2       
   6: imul          
   7: bipush        7
   9: imul          
  10: istore_3
```

and

```
intvar = (int) var1 * var3 * 7;
```

becomes:

```
   4: iload_1       
   5: iload_2       
   6: imul          
   7: bipush        7
   9: imul          
  10: istore_3
```

i.e. exactly identical.

Comment: Cool, I wish I could see the code after its compiled like that

Comment: @androidmaster But you can! Just use `javap -c SomeFile`.

Comment: How is that possible??? Do I have to use the sdk or is there a option in eclipse? So we use which ever one that is easier to read, right?

Comment: @androidmaster Run that command from terminal or command line whichever you have.

Comment: @androidmaster You use `javap` on the command line. If you're on Eclipse, try the [ASM plugin](http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/) (which is what I use, it's quite handy).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler removes *all* parentheses. If all the operands are integer, your two statements are identical from the point of view of the JLS and therefore of the compiler.

However if you had written

```
intvar = (int)((var1*(var2*7)))
```

the required order of execution is different so you would get different bytecode.